# using the class in the project group in all projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have small projects that are alike, using the same class,

I keep the same file in every project, But when I want to make a change, I have to visit all my projects and update them.

While developing a project in Delphi, I would put my related class in just one directory , I would just update in that class and build all of them, all projects would be updated at the same time

how do i do this in visual studio , I made a project group, I added a class to the group, but the projects in the group cannot access this class. How should I use a method?

1. common class I will use in all projects , 2nd and 3rd other projects, there is more

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should start with a class library (dll) project with your shared code, then add reference to that project/library on the projects you'll need to consume it.

Here's a Microsoft tutorial about this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio

Comment: I know it write dll, I was hoping I could do something without needing it

Answer (score 1):

You can create new project of dll library. This library can be referenced by all other projects. This is way how you can use the same interface in all other projects.

Comment: I know it write dll, I was hoping I could do something without needing it

Comment: I dont see why to avoid dll and I dont know any way how to have same files in two different projects. And I see it very dangerous. If you really need it, create some copy utility.

Comment: I'm lazy :) Delphi was also very easy, so I thought I could use it in the same way here. But if it's the most logical dll, let me start writing then